# Excel 2010, "Runtime Error '32809': Application-defined or object defined error"

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, macros

I am having this error when I open up certain workbooks that contain macros. The files are stored on a network drive and this error only happens on a few computers which leads me to believe the workbooks are not corrupted but that it is an issue with the individual PCs. I have tried common macro fixes within Excel as well as some fixes I found in older related posts with no luck. Has anyone fixed this before? Thanks,

Comment: On the PCs that get the error, have all the Microsoft Updates been installed for Windows and Office? Are those PCs running the same version as the PCs where the macro works?

Comment: It's pretty impossible to say anything without actually seeing the macros. If you get the errors when you open the workbooks, then look for macros starting automatically (e.g. `Workbook_Open`)

Comment: All updates have been installed. And yes they are on the same ver of Excel and Win7 64.

Comment: It depends on what the macros do, it depends on the environment... Too many things...